# OpenGL - Flickering with dynamic camera

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to implement a dynamic camera that follow my **Car** object, rotating in a way that it always points towards the car's front. The car is constantly moving, and this means that its *origin* property changes at every frame.

```
struct Point
{
    float x, y, z;
};  

struct Vector
{
    float dx, dy, dz;
public:
    Vector normalized() const; // returns the normalized vector   
    Point operator+(const Vector&) const; // Adds up a vector 
}


void draw() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1,0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    Point origin = car.origin; // The car's origin changes at every frame, 
                               // becase the car is moving

    // The direction vector points outwards the car'origin
    Vector direction = Vector(-origin.x, -origin.y, -origin.z).normalized();
    // The eye should be at a constant distance along the direction vector
    Point eye = origin + direction * 125.0;
    gluLookAt(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z, origin.x, origin.y, origin.z, 0, 1, 0);

    car.draw(); // calls the primitives that actually draw the car on the screen
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This causes a lot of flickering. If instead of pointing the camera towards the car's front, I make it look towards the -z axis and compute the eye Point this way:

```
Point eye = origin + Vector(0,0,125);
```

The flickering goes away. What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: Is the line of sight direction (from `eye` to `origin`) almost the same as the up vector (0, 1, 0)? Ideally the up vectro should be normal to the line of sight. Vectors that form a very sharp angle (have almost the same direction) can lead to inaccuracies.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried to use the cross product between the eye-object vector and the x axis versor as viewup vector, and the camera still flickers.

Comment: You are using the car's position as a direction offset. This can't be right. You probably meant to use the car's direction instead.